# Which clock does SO_TIMESTAMP socket option use?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, time, timestamp

I am receiving a stream of messages from a TCP server (a robot sending its status) every 0.1 s.  I can not guarantee that I call [`recvmsg`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recvmsg.2.html) every 0.1 s, so I would like to have a timestamp on those received messages so that when I `recvmsg` them I know if I've just received them, or if they had been in the buffer for long enough to be outdated and I should call `recvmsg` again until I read a recent msg.

First of all, which [clock](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) does the `struct timespec` of the [`SO_TIMESTAMP`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) timestamp use?  I've found sources on google that point to `CLOCK_REALTIME`, but they are around 10 years old, so they might be outdated.

Which of all the time functions should I call to get a time that's comparable to that of the timestamp?

Is it possible to use `CLOCK_BOOTTIME` to avoid continuity problems?

---

I made a mistake. I mixed `SO_TIMESTAMP` (uses `struct timeval`) with `SO_TIMESTAMPNS` (uses `struct timespec`) (`SO_TIMESTAMPNS` doesn't seem available).

While `SO_TIMESTAMPNS` doesn't seem available per the documentation, when I `#include <sys/socket.h>` I have it defined as `35`.

Comment: `but they are around 10 years old, so they might be outdated.` - no. The one rule about kernel, it does not break userspace. If it uses CLOCK_REALTIME, it will continue to use CLOCK_REALTME.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses `CLOCK_REALTIME`.

Puff. So: `SO_TIMESTAMP` is mentioned in [`sock_setsockopt`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.6/source/net/core/sock.c#L814). From there I jumped to [`sock_enable_timestamp`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.6/source/net/core/sock.c#L2522). But right above that function is [`sock_get_timestamp` and `sock_get_timestampns`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.6/source/net/core/sock.c#L2490). They use [`ktime_get_real`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.6/source/include/linux/timekeeping.h#L177). Just to check `sock_get_timestamp` is used in [`inet_ioctl` in af_inet.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.6/source/net/ipv4/af_inet.c#L852). Just to be sore I researched [documentation on ktime accessors](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/timekeeping.html) that `ktime_get_real` is the same as `CLOCK_REALTIME`. And `ktime_get_real` is also used by [`__net_timestamp` in socket buffer](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.6/source/include/linux/skbuff.h#L3099)

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**  The documentation was missing, so I wrote it.  It is documented in [`man 7 socket`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) in version 5.06 of the man-pages.

---

*Experimentally*, `SO_TIMESTAMPNS` works, and it looks like it's using `CLOCK_REALTIME`.

Therefore, the function to be used with `SO_TIMESTAMPNS` is `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tm);`

---

I don't know specific documentation for it, but I did some experiment:

I wrote a simple server and client test.

In the client side, I connected a socket specifying `SOCK_STREAM` and `"tcp"`.

Then I enabled timestamp in ns:

```
    int     enable = 1;

    if (setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TIMESTAMPNS, &enable,
                                                    sizeof(enable)))
            goto err;
```

Then I prepared the msg header:

```
    char            buf[BUFSIZ];
    char            cbuf[BUFSIZ];
    struct msghdr   msg;
    struct iovec    iov;

    iov.iov_base    = buf;
    memset(buf, 0, ARRAY_BYTES(buf));
    iov.iov_len     = ARRAY_BYTES(buf) - 1;
    msg.msg_name    = NULL;
    msg.msg_iov     = &iov;
    msg.msg_iovlen  = 1;
    msg.msg_control = cbuf;
    msg.msg_controllen = ARRAY_BYTES(cbuf);
```

And got some times before and after receiving the msg:

```
    struct timespec tm_before, tm_recvmsg, tm_after, tm_msg;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tm_before);
    usleep(500000);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tm_recvmsg);
    n   = recvmsg(sd, &msg, MSG_WAITALL);
    if (n < 0)
            goto err;
    usleep(1000000);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tm_after);
```

After that I read the timestamp of the msg:

```
    struct cmsghdr  *cmsg;

    for (cmsg = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&msg); cmsg; cmsg = CMSG_NXTHDR(&msg, cmsg)) {
            if (cmsg->cmsg_level == SOL_SOCKET  &&
                                    cmsg->cmsg_type == SCM_TIMESTAMPNS) {
                    memcpy(&tm_msg, CMSG_DATA(cmsg), sizeof(tm_msg));
                    break;
            }
    }
    if (!cmsg)
            goto err;
```

And finally printed the results:

```
    double      tdiff;

    printf("%s\n", buf);
    tdiff   = timespec_diff_ms(&tm_before, &tm_recvmsg);
    printf("tm_r - tm_b = %lf ms\n", tdiff);
    tdiff   = timespec_diff_ms(&tm_before, &tm_after);
    printf("tm_a - tm_b = %lf ms\n", tdiff);
    tdiff   = timespec_diff_ms(&tm_before, &tm_msg);
    printf("tm_m - tm_b = %lf ms\n", tdiff);
```

Which printed:

```
asdasdfasdfasdfadfgdfghfthgujty 6, 0;

tm_r - tm_b = 500.000000 ms
tm_a - tm_b = 1500.000000 ms
tm_m - tm_b = 18.000000 ms
```

---

System:

```
Linux debian 5.4.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.4.19-1 (2020-02-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux
gcc (Debian 9.3.0-8) 9.3.0
```

---

However, I didn't find any man page that talks about `SO_TIMESTAMPNS`, so this may not work on other systems.

---

I didn't test `SO_TIMESTAMP` because it uses `struct timeval` which AFAIK is [obsolete](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html).